# MVC1000 Use of IHtmlHelper.Partial may result in application deadlocks. Consider using <partial> Tag Helper or IHtmlHelper.PartialAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Trying to make a web app using .Netcore When I run the application I get this error. Help me
This is not a errors but a warning. But help me to resolve

I added my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <link href="~/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/sidebar-nav.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="fix-header fix-sidebar">
    <div id="wrapper">
        @Html.Partial("AdminPartials/_TopMenu")
        @Html.Partial("AdminPartials/_Sidebar")
        <div id="page-wrapper" style="min-height:600px">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                @RenderBody()
                <hr />
                <footer class="footer text-center">© @DateTime.Now.Year | Powered by Techguy</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/sidebar-nav.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/custom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In case you are looking just how to update from `@Html.Partial` to `<partial>`:

```
    @Html.Partial("AdminPartials/_TopMenu")
    @Html.Partial("AdminPartials/_Sidebar")
```

Should be changed to

```
    <partial name="AdminPartials/_TopMenu" />
    <partial name="AdminPartials/_Sidebar" />
```

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 9):

use

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_partialView", new List<Model>())
```

Comment: This answer should be the one considered correct. Not because the other one is wrong but because this is much more complete, it allows you to launch the partial view with a defined model.

Answer (score 5):

For the ones how as me are not so familiar with regex. You can do this change easily in whole solution using Find&Replace. It should do the job in most cases.

Find: `\@Html.Partial\(\"(.*?)\"\)`,

Replace: `<partial name="$1" />`,

option "Use regular expressions" checked

and

Find: `\@Html.Partial\(\"(.*?)\", (.*?)\)`,

Replace: `<partial name="$1" for="@($2)"/>`,

option "Use regular expressions" checked